# Read and write simultaneously from different indices of an associative array in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is it possible to read and write simultaneously (In parallel) from different indices of an associative array in System Verilog ?

Comment: Verilog or synthesizable Verilog?

Comment: Verilog testbench only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you from doing that. But like any variable you read and write from different processes, it's up to to you to make sure the data is valid and prevent race conditions.